# Finding partial text in range, return an index

Tags: excel

I need to find a partial text in a specific range and get a value which is X rows under cell index of found text. I have tried with INDEX and MATCH functions but without success.

[image: egzample]

As in example: looking for a partial of text `ASDFGHJK` and need returned the value three rows under: (`I NEED THIS VALUE`). I have tried to get a row index of found cell and +3 to get needed value ("I NEED THIS VALUE") but without success.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: so to summarize: you're looking for the text "ASDFGHJK" in any string in column G - and want to return the cell 3 rows below. Right?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use "wildcards" with `MATCH` so assuming "ASDFGHJK" in H1 as per Peter's reply you can use this regular formula

`=INDEX(G:G,MATCH("*"&H1&"*",G:G,0)+3)`

MATCH can only reference a single column or row so if you want to search 6 columns you either have to set up a formula with 6 MATCH functions or change to another approach - try this "array formula", assuming search data in A2:G100

`=INDIRECT("R"&REPLACE(TEXT(MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H1,A2:G100)),(ROW(A2:G100)+3)*1000+COLUMN(A2:G100))),"000000"),4,0,"C"),FALSE)`

confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Your method is working too, THX :) But have a question... What should i do to search in multiple column range? ( not in G:G range but for example A:G range ?)

Comment: I edited my answer to give a solution for multiple columns - if there is more than one match it takes the one in the lowest row....

Comment: Real Houdini ;) ITS WORKING :)

Comment: Thanks, save me a lot of time. If need to get the data of different column at the same row, the function is like this =INDEX(B:B;MATCH("string";A:A;0))

Comment: Thanks! By the way, if the number of the characters in the cell we search greater than 256, refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503745/excel-match-character-limit

Answer (score 12):

This formula will do the job:

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(SEARCH(H1,G:G)),0)+3)
```

you need to enter it as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. It assumes that the substring you're searching for is in cell `H1`.

Comment: Excellent! I had a similar question and modified your formula and it work exactly as wanted. Thnx

Comment: SEARCH() can be quite demanding in comparison to a MATCH-IF solution though.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this when googling to solve the same problem, and had to make a minor change to the solution to make it work in my situation, as I had 2 similar substrings, "Sun" and "Sunstruck" to search for. The offered solution was locating the wrong entry when searching for "Sun". Data in column B

I added another column C, formulaes C1=" "&B1&" " and changed the search to =COUNTIF(B1:B10,"* "&A1&" *")>0, the extra column to allow finding the first of last entry in the concatenated string.