# Excel MATCH character limit

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following formula **=INDEX(Dict!A:A,MATCH(A2,Dict!A:A,0),1)** but MATCH only works with text below 256 characters. Any way to overcome this limitiation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to overcome Excel Vlookup function limit of 256 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202473/way-to-overcome-excel-vlookup-function-limit-of-256-characters)

Comment: It does work above the limit, but only if the cells are exactly the same. What I need, however, is to be able to find partial matches. When I use wildcards with the formula (e.g. "\*"&A2&"\*"), I get #N/A.

Comment: What exceeds 256 characters, A2 or the values you are matching against?

Comment: BTW, I used this formula: =INDEX(Dict!A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Dict!A:A=A2,0),0))

Answer (score 6):

To accommodate partial matches use `SEARCH` like this:

`=INDEX(Dict!A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,Dict!A:A)),0),0))`

That will work to return a value > 256 characters but A2 can't be > 256 characters

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, this does work. However, the calculation time has increased dramatically. While earlier it took a fraction of a second, now it takes at least two seconds with one cell.

Comment: Yes, it will be slow referencing the whole column. If you can, use a fixed range like `Dict!A$2:A$1000` to speed up

Comment: I didn't notice your question about the 256 character limit. The answer is: the values I'm matching against. The A2 is always one word.

Comment: One more comment. The formula you suggested returns the same value regardless of if and where the wildcards appear: A2 VS. "*"&A2&"*" VS. "*"&A2 VS. A2&"*"

Comment: You don't need to use **any** wildcards with `SEARCH` - you can use the formula exactly as I wrote it. `SEARCH` automatically looks for A2 contained **within** other text

Comment: I see. However, I need to be able to use wildcards because I want the formula to first search for a given string at the beginning of the text (A2&"\*"), and only when it can't find it there to look further ("\*"&A2 or "\*"&A2&"\*"). I could use IF or simply have different formulas in consecutive cells. I would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LDMP look-up method, taking advantage of the concat formula available since the Excel 2016.

```
={CONCAT(IF(Value=A:A;B:B;"")}
```

Note that it is a matrix formula so you must enter it CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.
Additionally the formula returns not only the first value but all the matching values.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this, if you don't mind the messiness of a helper column, **and your original formula is not being repeated in subsequent rows (i.e. matching cells A3, A4, A5...)**.  The helper column can of course be hidden to keep DICT looking pretty.

1. Insert (or use) a column (say B:B) next to A:A in DICT!, and populate it with a simple formula "=A1=SHEET1!A$2" (SHEET1 being the name of your source/original sheet), which will populate the column with TRUE and FALSE values, indicating which rows (if any) in DICT match to A2.
2. The match syntax then changes from "MATCH(A2,Dict!A:A,0)" to "**MATCH(TRUE,Dict!B:B,0)**".

Note: I know this works in principle as I have just done it, but if I added a typo in retrofitting it to the example provided, apologies, however the principle should be easy to follow.